# Как сделать,чтобы при наведении на ссылку блок не сьежал?

Tags: html

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vmin;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.tile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 149);
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 2px black solid;
  z-index:3234;
}

.tile::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  left: -2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  /* border: 2px black solid; */
  z-index: 1;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 149);
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.tile:hover~.price {
  height: 116px;
}

.price:hover {
  height: 116px;
}

.tile:hover {
  top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<container class="container">
  <div class="tile">
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">INFO</a>
  </div>
</container>
```

Comment: а как должно быть ?

Comment: Ссылка не нажимается.

Comment: z-index: допишите

Comment: и ховер пишите от самого главного родителя

Comment: тогда наведении на ссылку .tile возвращается к первоначальному положению.

Comment: я показал пример