# Как сделать,чтоб при наведении на ссылку верхний блок(.tile)не сьежал вниз?

Tags: html, css

При наведении на ссылку верхняя часть опускается в первоначальное положение

Kак сделать, чтоб она не отпускалась?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vmin;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.tile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 149);
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 2px black solid;
  z-index:3234;
}
.price{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 149);
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.tile:hover~.price {
  height: 116px;
}

.price:hover {
  height: 116px;
}

.tile:hover {
  top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<container class="container">
    <div class="tile">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">INFO</a>
    </div>
</container>
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось же.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать,чтобы при наведении на ссылку блок не сьежал?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1258749/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb)

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20vmin;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.tile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 149);
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 2px black solid;
  z-index:3234;
}
.price{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 149);
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.tile:hover~.price {
  height: 116px;
}

.price:hover {
  height: 116px;
}

.container:hover .tile { /*Вот ваше решение*/
  top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<container class="container">
    <div class="tile">
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">INFO</a>
    </div>
</container>
```